# jQuery effect after pressing button

Tags: javascript

Drupal 6. I try to add jquerry effect after pressing button

```
$(function(){
    $('.node-add-to-cart').click(function() {
      $(".prod-pic").effect("transfer", { to: $("#block-uc_cart-0") }, 1000);
    });
});
```

But I get error object# has no method 'effect'.
I created a custom js file with this code and put a link to the template.php using drupal_add_js.
According to status report Jquerry UI 1.6 is installed. However, when inspecting html code, among scripts there is no jquery.ui loaded. Should I call it from my custom js file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal 6 version of JQuery is 1.26 and after install [jquery_update](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update) it will be updrade to 1.3.2

If you want persist use jquery method likes `effect` maybe this [article](http://drupal.org/node/1058168),but I think you can't using jquery 1.6 or upper in Drupal 6 .( I don't told you it's impossible but achieve this job is more struggle and maybe cause problem in other part of your site ).

maybe this [question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1197/using-a-newer-jquery-version) be helpful for you.

Comment: Ok I understand. Where can I find the list of all effects that can be done with 1.3.2 version? Thank you

Comment: Your welcome :)